# Next Without For / For Without Next / Loop Without Do / End If Without Block If Errors

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to print formulas to cells in specific worksheets whose names are in the predefined arrays.
I have the following code:

```
Private Sub bngComm_Click()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim colref1 As String, colref2 As String, colref3 As String

    For i = 13 To 134
    Do While IsInArray(Worksheets(i).Name, arrBingol)
        For j = 131 To 144
            If j = 136 Then

            Else
                For k = 2 To 13
                    If k = 2 Then
                        colref1 = "A"
                        colref2 = "E"
                        colref3 = "B"
                    ElseIf k = 3 Then
                        colref1 = "B"
                        colref2 = "F"
                        colref3 = "C"
                    ElseIf k = 4 Then
                        colref1 = "C"
                        colref2 = "G"
                        colref3 = "D"
                    ElseIf k = 5 Then
                        colref1 = "D"
                        colref2 = "H"
                        colref3 = "E"
                    ElseIf k = 6 Then
                        colref1 = "E"
                        colref2 = "I"
                        colref3 = "F"
                    ElseIf k = 7 Then
                        colref1 = "F"
                        colref2 = "J"
                        colref3 = "G"
                    ElseIf k = 8 Then
                        colref1 = "G"
                        colref2 = "K"
                        colref3 = "H"
                    ElseIf k = 9 Then
                        colref1 = "H"
                        colref2 = "L"
                        colref3 = "I"
                    ElseIf k = 10 Then
                        colref1 = "I"
                        colref2 = "M"
                        colref3 = "J"
                    ElseIf k = 11 Then
                        colref1 = "J"
                        colref2 = "N"
                        colref3 = "K"
                    ElseIf k = 12 Then
                        colref1 = "K"
                        colref2 = "O"
                        colref3 = "L"
                    ElseIf k = 13 Then
                        colref1 = "L"
                        colref2 = "P"
                        colref3 = "M"
                    End If
                Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k).FormulaLocal = "=(VLOOKUP(VALUE(MID(CELL(" & Chr(34) & "fılename" & Chr(34) & ";" & colref1 & CStr(j - 130) & ");FIND(" & Chr(34) & "]" & Chr(34) & ";CELL(" & Chr(34) & "fılename" & Chr(34) & ";" & colref1 & CStr(j - 130) & ");1)+1;30));'FTE GİDER DAĞILIM ANAHTARI'!$C:" & colref2 & ";" & CStr(k + 1) & ";0)/'FTE GİDER DAĞILIM ANAHTARI'!" & colref2 & "$7)*Premises!" & colref3 & CStr(j - 111)
                End If
            Next k
        Next j

        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

And it constantly gives Next Without For / For Without Next / Loop Without Do / End If Without Block If Errors whenever I try to fix one of them. I have checked to see if the statements are in correct order and I couldn't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: When you compile, it shows you exactly where it is wrong. It highlights the `End If` after the `Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k).FormulaLocal =`. Because there must be `next k` at that point.

Comment: I can't tell if your indentations are wrong in your original code or if they got messed up when you posted it here. Anyway - if you get "x without y" errors, make sure your indentations are correct. That is the fastest way to identify what's missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used  RUbberDuck (A fantastic free addin for VBA) to correctly indent your code.  I then deleted the long innermost if statement and the cause of your problem was patently clear.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub bngComm_Click()
Dim i                                           As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim colref1                                     As String, colref2 As String, colref3 As String

    For i = 13 To 134
        Do While IsInArray(Worksheets(i).Name, arrBingol)
            For j = 131 To 144
                If j = 136 Then

                Else
                    For k = 2 To 13

                        Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k).FormulaLocal = "=(VLOOKUP(VALUE(MID(CELL(" & Chr(34) & "filename" & Chr(34) & ";" & colref1 & CStr(j - 130) & ");FIND(" & Chr(34) & "]" & Chr(34) & ";CELL(" & Chr(34) & "filename" & Chr(34) & ";" & colref1 & CStr(j - 130) & ");1)+1;30));'FTE GIDER DAGILIM ANAHTARI'!$C:" & colref2 & ";" & CStr(k + 1) & ";0)/'FTE GIDER DAGILIM ANAHTARI'!" & colref2 & "$7)*Premises!" & colref3 & CStr(j - 111)
                    End If
                Next k
            Next j

            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

The Next K should be before the end if.

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. Thanks guys. I will definitely check the rubberduck stuff.

Answer (score 2):

As @GSerg said, you typed `Next k` in the wrong place. And so many ifs can be resumed with a `Select Case...End Select` statement.

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim colref1 As String, colref2 As String, colref3 As String

For i = 13 To 134
    Do While IsInArray(Worksheets(i).Name, arrBingol)
        For j = 131 To 144 Step 1
            If j = 136 Then
            Else
                For k = 2 To 13
                    Select Case k
                        Case 2: colref1 = "A": colref2 = "E": colref3 = "B"
                        Case 3: colref1 = "B": colref2 = "F": colref3 = "C"
                        Case 4: colref1 = "C": colref2 = "G": colref3 = "D"
                        Case 5: colref1 = "D": colref2 = "H": colref3 = "E"
                        Case 6: colref1 = "E": colref2 = "I": colref3 = "F"
                        Case 7: colref1 = "F": colref2 = "J": colref3 = "G"
                        Case 8: colref1 = "G": colref2 = "K": colref3 = "H"
                        Case 9: colref1 = "H": colref2 = "L": colref3 = "I"
                        Case 10: colref1 = "I": colref2 = "M": colref3 = "J"
                        Case 11: colref1 = "J": colref2 = "N": colref3 = "K"
                        Case 12: colref1 = "K": colref2 = "O": colref3 = "L"
                        Case 13: colref1 = "L": colref2 = "P": colref3 = "M"
                    End Select
                    Worksheets(i).Cells(j, k).FormulaLocal = "=(VLOOKUP(VALUE(MID(CELL(" & Chr(34) & "filename" & Chr(34) & ";" & colref1 & CStr(j - 130) & ");FIND(" & Chr(34) & "]" & Chr(34) & ";CELL(" & Chr(34) & "filename" & Chr(34) & ";" & colref1 & CStr(j - 130) & ");1)+1;30));'FTE GIDER DAGILIM ANAHTARI'!$C:" & colref2 & ";" & CStr(k + 1) & ";0)/'FTE GIDER DAGILIM ANAHTARI'!" & colref2 & "$7)*Premises!" & colref3 & CStr(j - 111)
                Next k
            End If
        Next j

        i = i + 1 '<--!!!!
    Loop
Next i
```

I'm really curious about your code, because you got `i = i + 1` inside a Do, and that's ok, but that `Do` is already inside a `For i=...` . I guess you have your reasons.

Also, now that you got  the `Select Case` part, you can see a clearly mathematical relation between the value of `k` and the columns, so probably you can even adapt that part, because the relation is `colref1 = k-1 : colref2 = k+3: colref3 = k` and use column numbers instead of letters. But this is just a suggestion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I literally just thought the same thing as per your last alinea =)

Comment: And if you go just one step further and use `FormulaR1C1Local`, you will not need the entire `select case` block and will be able to just use `k` directly. And if you go one step further yet and switch to `FormulaR1C1`, amending the formula accordingly to use en-us function names and separators, then the code will also work on any localized Excel, not just in `tr-tr`.

Comment: i = i + 1 is there because i needs to be incremented each time the Do statement loops, not only when it breaks and goes to the For loop. I will try using the Select Case blocks. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a breakdown of your problem (the others took care of that), I just want to show you how you could simplify your `IF` statements:

```
Sub Test()

Dim k As Long
Dim colref1 As String, colref2 As String, colref3 As String

For k = 2 To 13
    colref1 = Chr(63 + k): colref2 = Chr(67 + k): colref3 = Chr(64 + k)
Next k

End Sub
```